# magento customer_save_after model / observer not called, catch customer -> edit -> save function

Tags: magento

I'm new on magento and trying to write little extension for it (magento 1.7).

I have created tab in customer->edit, it prints multiselect, thats ok, the problem is that i cant get in observer file to catch multiselect options before saving and save them to my custom table in database.

there is some code snippets:
app/code/local/Gone/Brands/etc/config.xml

```
    <adminhtml>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <customertab>
                <file>customertab.xml</file>
            </customertab>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <events>
        <customer_save_after>
            <observers>
                <brands_hide_manufacturers>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>Gone_Brands_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>saveHideManufacturers</method>
                </brands_hide_manufacturers>
            </observers>
        </customer_save_after>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

app/code/local/Gone/Brands/Model/Observer.php

```
<?php
class Gone_Brands_Model_Observer
{
 public function _construct()
 {
    echo "ssssssssssssssssssssssssssss";
    echo "<script>alert('aaa');</script>";
 }

 public function saveHideManufacturers() {
    echo "ssssssssssssssssssssssssssss";
    echo "<script>alert('bbbb');</script>";
 }
}
```

Maye there are other solutions how to catch form from customer->edit -> my created tab with custom field?

Thank you.

```
==================================================================================
```

Finally, four hours spent for this. Maybe this helps for someone else.

config.xml

```
customer_save_after -> change to -> adminhtml_customer_save_after
```

Now works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, four hours spent for this. Maybe this helps for someone else.

config.xml

```
customer_save_after -> change to -> adminhtml_customer_save_after
```

Now works.

Answer (score 0):

In magento you doesn't  link to a class with its full class name.. you must use the framework :

replace :

```
<class>Gone_Brands_Model_Observer</class>
```

by :

```
<class>gonebrands/observer</class>
```

"gonebrands" (or whatever) refers to your XML node defining your MODEL layer in your config.xml

Comment: when im doing like that it doesnt work, it says: Warning: include(Mage/Gonebrands/Model/Observer.php), if i do gone_brands/observer it looks in Mage/Gone/Brands/Model
But for the my mistake i found issue:
customer_save_after -> change to -> adminhtml_customer_save_after

Comment: the syntax I gave you is the right one but you have to adapt it with your own module layers definition. Go to  :http://www.pierrefay.com/event-observers-magento-tutorial-howto-105 for more explanations

Comment: @Bixi Are you sure you can't use Full class name? You CAN.

Comment: just for example.. check this file app/code/core/Mage/Cms/etc/config.xml .. and in Magento2 you will only see Full class names instead of class alias

Comment: ir works but it's a bad practice cause it bypass totally the model's rewrite's mechanisms ... In magento using a direct classname access should be done in very specific cases...

Answer (score 0):

Event definition must be inside "global" tag. Also 
you don't need a _construct method in your observer class

```
<global>
    <events>
        <customer_save_after>
            <observers>
                <brands_hide_manufacturers>
                   <type>singleton</type>
                   <class>Gone_Brands_Model_Observer</class>
                   <method>saveHideManufacturers</method>
                </brands_hide_manufacturers>
            </observers>
        </customer_save_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

Comment: "Event definition must be inside "global" tag. " => That is absolutely not true : you can have event affecting only frontend or only backend or both (global) ...